# Node.js equivalent of bash pipe stdout redirection

Tags: node.js, git, bash, child-process

I am having this command I use to get the contents inside a git repository:

```
git archive --remote=ssh://git@git/repository.git HEAD filename.txt | tar xvOf -
```

The first part of the command returns the contents of `filename.txt` inside the repository to the standard output.
The second part is there in order to remove the `pax_global_header` that git automatically adds to the contents.

I want to implement this command as a spawned child_process on `node.js` `v0.10.36`

Here is what I've tried:

```
var git = spawn("git",  ["archive","--remote=" + repositoryUrl,"HEAD",filename]);
var tar = spawn("tar", ["xvOf", "-"]);
var out = [];
tar.stdout.pipe(git.stdout).on('data', function(data){
        var string = data.toString();
        if(string) {
            out.push(string);
        }
    });
```

but when I run this, the strings I get inside the data handler are like the `git` output never gets piped through the `tar` process

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer 10 seconds after posting this...

What I should do was pipe the output of `git` to the input of `tar` and work with the streams outputted by `tar`

So my code looks somewhat like this:

```
    var git = spawn("git",  ["archive","--remote=" + repositoryUrl,"HEAD",filename]);
    var tar = spawn("tar", ["xvOf", "-"]);

    var out = [];
    git.stdout.pipe(tar.stdin);

    tar.stdout.on('data', function(data){
        var string = data.toString();
        if(string) {
            out.push(string);
        }
    });
....
```